# «Хотя никакой срочности нет(,) ещё успеется». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

*Их толкнули невидимые руки, кто-то неведомо зачем решил передвинуть, хотя никакой срочности нет, ещё успеется.*
Нужна ли запятая между "нет" и "ещё"?

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Их толкнули невидимые руки, (2) кто-то неведомо зачем решил (их) передвинуть, (3) хотя никакой срочности нет, (4) ещё успеется.**

Запятая ставится.

Это сложное предложение с бессоюзной и союзной (подчинительной) связью.

Предложениями 1 и 2 и предложения 3 и 4 связаны подчинительным союзом ХОТЯ, но при этом между предложениями 3 и 4 **бессоюзная сочинительная связь**, которая обозначается **запятой**.

Answer (score 1):

[**успе́ется**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/259788/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)
**I.** *сов. неперех. разг.; безл.*
О ситуации, когда ещё есть время и можно не торопиться.
**II.** *предик. разг.*
Об отсутствии необходимости спешить; не к спеху.

Вот [полное предложение](https://www.rulit.me/books/vse-dushi-read-29084-3.html).

> Тишина расстилается всего шире там, где ее нарушают лишь отдельные прерывистые голоса либо звуки, например лязг вагона, который вдруг продвинется загадочным образом на несколько метров и остановится, либо невнятный крик носильщика, который прикорнул было, но тут же проснулся — от холода и чтобы не досматривать дурного сна; или вдали громыхнут ящики — **их толкнули невидимые руки, кто-то неведомо зачем решил передвинуть, хотя никакой срочности нет, еще успеется**; либо звякнет жестянка из-под пива, которую сплющили и швырнули в урну, либо прошуршит газетный лист в непритязательном своем полете, либо послышатся мои собственные шаги, когда, чтобы скоротать ожидание, подхожу бесцельно к самому краю платформы, как в Англии именуют перрон.

Первое. Если Вы приводите только часть предложения, то при цитировании эту часть необходимо обрамить многоточиями:
*...их толкнули невидимые руки, кто-то неведомо зачем решил передвинуть, хотя никакой срочности нет, еще успеется...*

Второе. Поначалу очень хочется в указанном месте поставить тире (*хотя никакой срочности нет — еще успеется* [= еще не к спеху, еще время терпит]), но в контексте **всего** массивного предложения, думаю, запятая стоит правильно — между двумя предикативами (а тире уже имеется).

*А чего спешить, еще успеется,

Будет море, будет южный жар,

И получишь ты загар индейца

Или солнечный удар!*
Юлий Ким. Ты только посмотри